# Updating related entities

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, partial-views, razor-pages

`AppUser` identity model:

`public virtual ICollection<UserPhones> UserPhones { get; set; }`

Using Razor Pages, I call a partial view, like so:

`@await Html.PartialAsync("_NameAndID", Model.AppUser)`

PageModel:

```
[BindProperty]
public AppUser AppUser { get; set; }

 public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        AppUser = _userManager.Users
                //.Include(x => x.UserAddresses) //OMITTED BC USING LAZY LOADING
                .SingleOrDefaultAsync(x => x.UserName == 
                     _httpContext.HttpContext.User.Identity.Name).Result;

        return Page();
    }
```

Within `_NameAndID.cshtml`, I explicitly reference a particular telephone from the `UserPhones` entity.  With:

```
<input type="hidden" asp-for="UserPhones
   .SingleOrDefault(z => z.Type == EnumPhoneType.Mobile).UserPhoneId" />

//other properties removed for brevity           

<div class="rvt-grid__item">
    <label asp-for="UserPhones.SingleOrDefault(z => z.Type == EnumPhoneType.Mobile).PhoneNumber">Mobile Phone</label>
    <input asp-for="UserPhones.SingleOrDefault(z => z.Type == EnumPhoneType.Mobile).PhoneNumber" autocomplete="tel" />
    <span asp-validation-for="UserPhones.SingleOrDefault(z => z.Type == EnumPhoneType.Mobile).PhoneNumber"></span>
</div>
```

At runtime, the explicit mobile phone number is loaded properly.  However when posting to `public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()` the related `AppUser.UserPhones` is `null`.  (**The problem**)

Can you help?

Thank you in advance!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### The Reason

The `asp-for` does not work well for this scenario.

Considering your code in `_NameAndID.cshtml` :

```
<input asp-for="UserPhones.SingleOrDefault(z => z.Type == EnumPhoneType.Mobile).PhoneNumber" autocomplete="tel" />
```

Note the LINQ extension method `.SingleOrDefault(...)` here. **The `asp-for` here does not know how to get the name for `UserPhones.SingleOrDefault(z => z.Type == EnumPhoneType.Mobile).PhoneNumber`， so it just render it as `PhoneNumber`**. As a result, the rendered html will be :

```
<input autocomplete="tel" type="text" id="PhoneNumber" name="PhoneNumber" value="">
```

Let's say someone inputs an value of `911`,  when posted to server, the payload will be :

```
PhoneNumber=911
```

As your page model on server side is :

```
    [BindProperty]
    public AppUser AppUser{get;set;}

    public IActionResult OnGet()
    {
        // ...
    }

    public IActionResult OnPostAsync() 
    {
        return Page();
    }
```

Note the `AppUser.UserPhones` property is a collection. in other words, `AppUser` expects a payload like :

```
UserPhones[0].UserPhoneId=1&UserPhones[0].PhoneNumber=911&UserPhones[1].UserPhoneId=2&UserPhones[1].PhoneNumber=119
```

However, what you send to the server is :

```
PhoneNumber=911
```

So the `App.UserPhones` will always be null and the `AppUser.PhoneNumber` property will be `911`.

#### How to Fix

Firstly, in order to bind the `UserPhones` automatically, I change the type of `App.UserPhones` to `IList<UserPhones>` , so that we can use a index syntax

```
public class AppUser : IdentityUser{

    // public virtual ICollection<UserPhones> UserPhones { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<UserPhones> UserPhones { get; set; }

}
```

Secondly, don't use complex query in `asp-for`, use simple index syntax instead. For example, if you would like to post some `UserPhones` or post all `UserPhones`, you can add an index for each field :

```
@for(var i=0;i <Model.UserPhones.Count(); i++) {

    <div class="rvt-grid__item">
        <label asp-for="@Model.UserPhones[i].UserPhoneId"></label>
        <input asp-for="@Model.UserPhones[i].UserPhoneId"/>
        <label asp-for="@Model.UserPhones[i].PhoneNumber"></label>
        <input asp-for="@Model.UserPhones[i].PhoneNumber"/>
        <span asp-validation-for="@Model.UserPhones[i].PhoneNumber"></span>
    </div>
}
```

In this way, when someone submits the form, `AppUser.UserPhones` will be the correctly set. Here's a screenshot of demo :

[image]

Comment: Thank you @itminus!  This is exactly what I ended up doing yesterday and it worked like a champ.  Considering converting to a tag helper though so that I can make it reusable throughout the application where the phone number needs edited.  Thanks again!

Comment: Hi again @itminus, I posted a the custom tag helper idea if you are interested in helping with that as well.  No worries if not.  Thanks again.  See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53395905/complex-custom-tag-helper